# Why need to set up "UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory) in ASP.NET Core MVC"?

Tags: asp.net-core

Why need to set up `UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory)` in ASP.NET Core MVC?

[image]

Comment: Take look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting I think it's good for you.

Comment: Indeed, this link explains everything clearly, should be the validated answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 15):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting) (which in this case I wrote):

> Specifying Directory.GetCurrentDirectory as the content root will use the web project's root folder as the app's content root when the app is started from this folder (for example, calling dotnet run from the web project folder). This is the default used in Visual Studio and dotnet new templates.

If you don't add this, the content root will default to the application root, which is wherever the program is running from (probably somewhere in a /bin folder). This usually isn't what you want if you're launching the web app from its source/project root.